# Sequelize dando erro ao tentar conectar ao banco de dados “Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0”

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, postgresql, sequelize-js

Estou tentando estabelecer uma conexão com meu banco de dados postgres usando o sequelize, quando tento conectar ele acusa o seguinte erro, mesmo com o parâmetro dialect estando definido, ainda assim ele diz que deve estar explícito

Meu código:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, {
    host:'localhost',
    dialect:'postgres'
});

try {
    sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Conexão estbabelecida com sucesso')
}catch{
    console.log('Erro ao estabelecer conexão');
}

const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');

const routes = require('./routes')
const path = require('path');


app.use(express.urlencoded({  extended:true }));

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));

const sessionOptions = session({
    secret:process.env.cookie_secret,
    store: new (require('connect-pg-simple')(session))(),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7}
});
```

Erro

> Error: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0 at new Sequelize (C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\ExpressEWebpack\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:281:13) at Object. (C:\Users\lopes\Desktop\Javascript\novo-projeto\ExpressEWebpack\server.js:5:19) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12) at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

Comment: Não faltou um terceiro parametro  `password` antes do objeto? [veja](https://sequelize.org/v4/)

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar, meu banco não tem uma senha, e quando eu colocava esse parâmetro, ele acusava outro erro, onde dizia "client password must be a string", a qual não consegui corrigir de jeito nenhum,só quando tirei o parâmetro password,aí agora ele passou a acusar o dialeto, onde já está declarado

Comment: Voce passou `null` como parametro ou o que?

Comment: Se vc usa o arquivo `config.json`, mostre ele.

Comment: Não passei null nem nada, e não estou usando o arquivo json